# Why am i getting NoSuchElementException while using scanner

Tags: java, nosuchelementexception

When i run my code i get a NoSuchElementException error. I want the input to be a file path that will be passed to the File class and then to BufferReader.

Output:

```
Enter directory: 
java.util.NoSuchElementException
in java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:907)
in java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1416)
in test.atest(test.java:33)
in (OUWorkspace:1)
```

My Code:

```
public void atest(){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter directory: ");
    String path = sc.next();
    String pathname = OUFileChooser.getFilename(path);
    File aFile = new File(pathname);
    BufferedReader br = null;

    try
    {
        String currentLine;
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(aFile));
        currentLine = br.readLine();
        while (currentLine != null)
        {

            System.out.println(currentLine);
            currentLine = br.readLine();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception anException)
    {
        System.out.println("Error: " + anException);
    }
    finally
    {
        try
        {
            br.close();
        }
        catch (Exception anException)
        {
            System.out.println("Error: " + anException);
        }
    }
}
```

Line 33 is : String path = sc.next();

Comment: add as a comment which line is 33

Comment: Since your Scanner is trying to read from `System.in` and is throwing this exception it suggests that you must have closed `System.in` somewhere earlier. Remember that invoking `close()` on outer stream/reader also invokes `close()` on wrapped stream.

Comment: Usually it is caused by fact that you are creating many separate instances of Reader/Scanner which wrap `System.in`. Don't do that. Create one Scanner and pass it to methods which need it. Close it at the end of your application when you are sure you no longer need to read from `System.in`.

Comment: Line 33 is : String path = sc.next();        there is only one scanner instantiated, the one in the code above. also, this is the only method in this class.

Comment: How is that method invoked? Scanner or other Reader which is wrapping `System.in` probably exist in other methods which are invoked by same JVM in different places and at the end they close such wrapper, meaning it will also close `System.in` causing this error.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/MjQk4UZ9 - this is the whole class. nothing else is using scanner in the class. and no other classes.

Comment: I don't see `main` method there which is entry point for *every* Java application. This suggests that there exist some framework which is using your class. Is it possible that framework is configured to close System.in, or executes some of your other code (which you maybe forgot) which closes System.in?